# Convert special characters to HTML entities

Tags: php, character-encoding

I have a HTML file and when I view it in notepad, I can see the following:

```
<p><span>Copyright © 2008 Your Company Name</span>
```

Notice the copyright symbol:

I load the HTML and perform this on it:

```
$html = file_get_contents('test.html');
$html = mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8");
file_put_contents('output.html', $html);
```

When I view the html again in notepad, the copyright symbol has disappeared and is replaced by a space?!

I  want the copyright symbol to be replaced by a `&copy;` or `&#169`. Is this not what `mb_convert_encoding` with the `HTML-ENTITIES` option does?

This is the [test HTML file](http://opensourcetemplates.org/templates/preview/environmental-brand/) I am using.

Comment: Why? What is wrong with a real copyright symbol? It is easier to read and uses fewer bytes.

Comment: What does `htmlentities($html, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8')` do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your test HTML page is **not** encoded in UTF-8; therefore, when `mb_convert_encoding` sees the copyright character (ordinal value 169) it doesn't know what to do with what it perceives as an invalid UTF-8 sequence.

You should therefore specify the correct input encoding when calling `mb_convert_encoding`:

```
$html = mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'ISO-8859-1');
```

Alternatively, you can use something like

```
$html = htmlentities($html, ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401, 'ISO-8859-1');
```

**Note:** I am answering your question directly, but you don't say what you need the conversion for. It's possible that there may be a better way to achieve your goal.

Comment: Very interesting. I could probably use `mb_detect_encoding` rather than assuming its `UTF-8` all the time.

Comment: @Abs: Not really. You should *know* what the encoding is, or otherwise ask a definitive source (e.g. the server that supplies the content). Encoding "detection" is hacky by nature and will not always work correctly. The human equivalent would be showing someone text in a language they don't know at all and asking what it is. You might be able to tell that it's "most likely northern european", but that's not good enough.

Comment: I understand, Jon. But if a user submits text/html through a form you won't know the encoding and not all browsers support the accept-charset in HTML forms. So the only option left is the auto detection of encoding, right?

Comment: @Abs: Without `accept-charset` the encoding for submitted text will be the same encoding as the page containing the form was displayed in.

Answer (score 0):

If you are serving your html as UTF-8 the correct action is surely: nothing.

```
<p><span>Copyright © 2008 Your Company Name</span>
```

Is perfectly valid html - just look at the page source for *this* page.

Comment: Interestingly, if the © is pulled from a non UTF-8 database table, serving it up in a UTF-8 encoded page doesn't actually work, even if the stored symbol looks identical to the UTF-8 version.

Comment: You are simply describing the consequences of not having the database collation, the db connection, the db data, the html source and the meta charset all having the same encoding Typel. Note that there's no mention of a database in the question.